# When I borrow a bond, do I pay owner the coupons?

Tags: fixed-income, repo

Or do I get to keep them for the duration of the repo transaction?

Comment: "in the case of repurchase transactions, the buyer agrees to immediately pay compensatory amounts to the seller equivalent to any income payment received on the collateral." https://www.icmagroup.org/Regulatory-Policy-and-Market-Practice/repo-and-collateral-markets/icma-ercc-publications/frequently-asked-questions-on-repo/22-who-is-entitled-to-receive-coupons-dividends-or-other-income-payments-on-a-security-being-used-as-collateral-in-a-repo/

Comment: @noob2 So then -- yes -- I pay the owner the coupons; in addition to any repo rate I am already paying to borrow.

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger note that the net effect is null: you receive the coupons and pay a compensatory amount equal to the coupons’ value.

Comment: Technically you pay the PB who lent you the bonds and they remit the payment to the owner of the bond.